# Why an extra slash is getting added to urls?

Tags: django, dotcloud

I've created a blog using django and hosted it on dotcloud  http://www.honeybunny.dotcloud.com/blog/ its working fine on the localhost but when i try to access it online an extra slash is added to the urls what could be the reason ?

> www.sitename.com/admin/

becomes

> www.sitename.com//admin/

my urls.py is as following

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
import blog
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',redirect_to,{'url':'/blog'}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/',include('blog.urls')),
)
```

Also submitting the login form on the admin redirects me to http://admin/ while in the local environment it works perfectly fine .

UPDATE : My problem seems remarkably similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056967/django-double-slash-in-urls-issue-multiple-webservers-apache-and-nginx) .

Comment: @kracekumar try again i had pushed the url.py with an $ at the end of urls like you described below .Also I don't understand why is it behaving in a different manner on local and production environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem with dotcloud the same code worked without any errors when i uploaded it to epio

Answer (score 0):

From django tutorials the url file should look like the one below.

`from django.conf.urls.defaults import *`

`urlpatterns = patterns('',
          (r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),

          (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),

          (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),

          (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'honeybunny.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^honeybunny/', include('honeybunny.foo.urls')),

            # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
                # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

                    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
                        url(r'^$',redirect_to,{'url':'/blog'}),
                            url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)),
                                )
```

Is my `urls.py` file
[image: Django Admin]

I have deleted `import blog` line because I don't have blog module.

Comment: works fine for me too in the local environment, its not working correctly on the dotcloud

Comment: and yeah the localenvironment and dotcloud both have the same version of the code just in case you were wondering .